# Open web-generated text file in excel

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, csv, http-headers

I generate text files in a web application, and I would like the client (mainly IE11 running on Windows 7 and 8) to directly open the files in Excel.

I serve the files as:

`Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Disposition: filename="myfile.txt"`

and the content of the file is something like this:

`abc <tab> def <tab> ghi
123 <tab> 456 <tab> <789>`

When a Windows IE11 user downloads this file, the file extension will be forcibly changed to ".xls" when the data content is 4096 bytes or larger. Thus, Excel will then complain about "invalid file format" (of course) when trying to open the file, having text-only content.

When the file is less than 4096 bytes, the extension ".txt" will be un-touched, and Excel will happily open the file.

The same thing happens if I use a ".htm" extension (using a HTML data content).

Any solutions to this, how to make Excel open the file without problems?

If I instead use extension ".csv" (Content-Disposition: filename="myfile.csv") it never gets renamed - probably as CSV is a file format that kind of belongs to Excel.
However ".csv" files need to use "," or ";" as field delimiters, according to the user locale, and I'd prefer using `<tab>` instead.
(also, I'd actually really prefer to use HTML data content as well)

So - why does Windows/IE11 rename the file to ".xls" when it is 4096 bytes or larger?
And/or, is there any "best practice" to get Excel to automatically open a text file delivered from the web?

Comment: You do know there are free libraries available that are capable of generating Excel files? Perhaps you can utilise one of those and not generate a txt but a real Excel file.

Comment: Well no we cannot write XLS in this environment, so it must be text files - text or html

Comment: By the way, I found a (quote undocumented?) feature that makes it possible to force Excel to use a specific field delimiter (like <tab>) in the CSV parsing - by adding a row "sep=x" at the top of the file (and setting "x" to <tab>). This may be a way around the problem, but I really would like to be able to use HTML as well, so then the 4096 limit still seems very intriguing :-)